# arecord -N handler is not working - it start to record even if there is a running process

Tags: shell-script, cron

From arecord man:

> -N, --nonblock
> Open the audio device in non-blocking mode. If the device is busy the program will exit immediately. If this option is not set the program will block until the audio device is available again.

But if I start a recording with crontab, after a minute, it tries to start again. The -N handler isn't responding as it should...

the crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * home/pi/record.sh
```

record.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
dateis=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
arecord -v -f dat -r 48 -D hw:1,0 -d 300 -c 2 -N | lame -r -h - record-"$dateis".mp3
```

It's supposed to wait until the 5 min recording of the former arecord process is finished. Instead it starts to record every minute, as if there isn't any process to block it.

Comment: You are wrong, it exits immediately saying the device is busy.

Comment: see my answer, please. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem was that the lame command was executing without an input.
so the N hendler worked for arecord but it did'nt stopped the lame from being executed.
is that make sense?

Comment: It does.  So did you find a number of lame processes hanging?

Comment: yap. but if so, that is not the proper way to regulate this multi-process cause i don't want to create junk files. so i would record only WAV and convert them afterwards. thanks.